# 3 count and sum in same table group by date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table similar as below

```
|   DATE   |   FULL/PART   |    AMMOUNT    |    CODETYPE    |
|2014-01-02|     PART      |     3.00      |       02       |
|2014-01-02|     PART      |    10.00      |       02       |
|2014-01-03|     PART      |     5.00      |       01       |
|2014-01-03|     FULL      |    10.00      |       03       |
|2014-01-01|     FULL      |    10.00      |       01       |
|2014-01-01|     FULL      |    10.00      |       01       |
```

I wanted to generate a statistic output as below

```
|   DATE   |    CODETYPE    |  SUM(AMMOUNT)FULL | COUNT(AMMOUNT)FULL |  SUM(AMMOUNT)PART |  COUNT(AMMOUNT)PART|
|2014-01-01|       01       |        20.00      |           2        |         0.00      |           0        |
|2014-01-03|       03       |        10.00      |           1        |         0.00      |           0        |
|2014-01-03|       01       |         0.00      |           0        |         5.00      |           1        |
|2014-01-02|       02       |         0.00      |           0        |        13.00      |           2        |
```

Query I have so far:-

```
SELECT DATE,CODETYPE,sum(AMMOUNT),count(AMMOUNT) 
FROM myTABLE
WHERE CODETYPE='01' && FULL/PART='FULL' && DATE BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-01-31'


SELECT DATE,CODETYPE,sum(AMMOUNT),count(AMMOUNT) 
FROM myTABLE
WHERE CODETYPE='02' && FULL/PART='PART' && DATE BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-01-31'


SELECT DATE,CODETYPE,sum(AMMOUNT),count(AMMOUNT) 
FROM myTABLE
WHERE CODETYPE='03' && FULL/PART='PART' && DATE BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-01-31'
```

and finally `GROUP BY DATE,CODETYPE`

Every date has full or part, different CODETYPE(01,02,03,...) and I have to summarize the data into the output above which is,

DATE 2014-01-01, sum() and count() the AMMOUNT where CODETYPE='01' and group by date

How should I achieve it? Or is there any query function could solve this problem that I didnt know about(Im new to sql)?

**EDIT**:
The Date range and CODETYPE is based on user desire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT DATE, CODETYPE,
       SUM(CASE WHEN `FULL/PART` = 'FULL' THEN AMOUNT END) as AMOUNT_FULL,
       SUM(`FULL/PART` = 'FULL') as CNT_FULL,
       SUM(CASE WHEN `FULL/PART` = 'PART' THEN AMOUNT END) as AMOUNT_PART,
       SUM(`FULL/PART` = 'PART') as CNT_PART
FROM myTABLE
WHERE FDATE BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-01-31'
GROUP BY DATE, CODETYPE
```

Comment: much more elegant than what I suggested. didn't know you could do that.

Comment: You must use count for CNT_FULL and CNT_PART

Comment: @IndraKumarS . . . I have no idea what you mean.  The above code is correct.  If you used `count()`, you would get the wrong answer.  MySQL treats booleans as integers in a numeric context, where true is 1 and false is 0.  The `sum()` calculates the number of matching values.

Comment: I am getting SQL syntax error near `SUM(CASE WHEN `FULL/PART` = 'FULL' THEN AMOUNT END) as AMOUNT_FULL,`

Comment: @ChanChunWeng . . . Are you sure you have the backticks and quotes in the right places?  The version in your comment is missing a backtick before `FULL`, for instance.

Comment: @GordonLinoff No, I was wanted to "highlight" the code

Comment: @ChanChunWeng . . . Perhaps it was the missing comma at the end of the third expression in the `SELECT`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry, I highlighted the wrong line. It was line 4:SUM(CASE WHEN `FULL/PART` = 'PART' THEN AMOUNT END) as AMOUNT_PART,

Comment: @ChanChunWeng . . . That would have been due to the missing comma typo.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, You're right. But I get empty set as result.

Comment: @ChanChunWeng . . . The number of result rows is determined by the `where`.  Are you sure that is correct?

Comment: @GordonLinoff This is embarrassing, you are right. The date in my database was september and december.. Thanks for your help man!!!